# How to get office back?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2013, clean-install

I want to get back my office 2013 which came pre-installed with my laptop. I did a clean install of windows. I got my windows back but didn't got office.

Note : Office was pre-installed so I have no product key and laptop seller didn't gave us purchase proof

This question already has answer but that answer didn't solve my problem

Comment: Only way to get it back is use the laptop manufacturers Restore disks. Make and model of laptop?

Comment: @Moab Manufacturer : Dell Inc. Model: Inspiron 15 3000 series 3567

Comment: Is the factory recovery partition still there? Look in disk management, there should be a several gigabyte partition?

Comment: See this page, download the software, it will allow you to download the Dell factory image to restore your PC>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/osiso/recoverytool/WT64A

Comment: @Moab There is EFI system partion which 512MB

Comment: thats not it, use the tool i posted to make a usb recovery drive for your system. The use that to restore your PC.